# Regular Expression to match only the first block of text

Tags: regex

The text below has 3 blocks that start with `/*+` and end with `/*-`. The regular expression `(/[*][+]a[*]/)((?s).*)(/[*][-]a[*]/)\R` matches all the text below. How can I match only the first block?

```
TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT

/*+a*/
--TEXT 1
--TEXT 1
/*-a*/

TEXT TEXT TEXT

/*+x*/
--TEXT 2
--TEXT 2
/*-x*/

TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT

/*+a*/
--TEXT 3
--TEXT 3
/*-a*/

TEXT TEXT TEXT
TEXT TEXT TEXT
```

Comment: `((?s).*)` -> `((?s).*?)`, see https://regex101.com/r/GCu3lh/1.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!